# Batch file %-dp0 not working

Tags: batch-file, filepath

I am working on a batch file at the moment.

It requires a calling of a VBS and a REG so I used the %-dp0 variable to get the folder path. However, it seems to give me the equivalent of the system32 path.

What is the problem here and are there any equivalents?

Here is my code:

```
cd %-dp0
cscript.exe VBS.vbs
cscript.exe VBS2.vbs
goto :eof
```

And:

```
cd %-dp0
regedit.exe Regedit.reg
goto :eof
```

It returns something like this:

Can't find C:\WINDOWS\system32\VBS.vbs

Comment: Try to add `echo %~dp0` and `echo %CD%` after your `CD`. Btw. `CD` without `/D` option will not change the drive

Comment: The use of the tilde is documented in the `CALL` and `FOR` commands.

Comment: **This question was caused by a simple typographical error.**

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I think there is a typo in your script
Instead of **`%-dp0`** you should write it like this with tilde **`%~dp0`**

And your script becomes like this :

```
cd %~dp0
cscript.exe VBS.vbs
cscript.exe VBS2.vbs
goto :eof
```

Comment: You have better eyes than me, I haven't seen the difference